# Format LINQ code in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, linq, code-formatting

Does anyone know how can I auto-reformat LINQ code in VS 2010? For example you can format C# code with ctrl+k+d.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl K D will format LINQ also.  If it's not formatting it, that's probably due to a syntax error.  Usually when you hit the ; at the end of the LINQ statement, it formats itself more nicely.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the Linq (plus a few surrounding lines?)